# Name of Zaraki Kenpachi's Zanpakuto?

Tags: bleach

In the manga, Kenpachi can't hear his Zanpakuto's sound at all in the beginning. But when he's battling with Captain Unohana (previous Kenpachi, I heard), he began to hear his Zanpakuto's speaking. Does anyone know the Zanpakuto's name or its abilities?

Comment: It is not yet known. I am sure it will be revealed as the arch continues.

Comment: hope it continues as soon as possible, but is there no speculation or rumor for the most-likely the Zanpakuto's name?

Comment: @AbieGiordano: Nope, I'm guessing we'll find out soon enough though :P

Comment: @MadaraUchiha haha, good enough, I just can't wait for the continuation of the series

Comment: maybe edit the title to a more question like format ;) ?

Comment: But zangetzu was a manifestation of hie Quincy powers not the true name of his zanpakto.

Comment: you're confusing something here. the question i about zaraki kenpachi, the captain of squad 10 and not about ichigo

Comment: I dont entirely trust the internet but i looked it up on the images and one of them have him holding a big ass sycth like sword with a skull attached to it in the middle..i dont know if thats his bankai but it looks like it.

Comment: Everybody in the sternritter arc (well almost atleast.) Has them a bankai..so you know eventually he will get his.

Comment: Well...it hasn't been officially verified yet - pictures from the 'Net aren't entirely authentic or correct.

Comment: That doesn't really answer the question though. The question was about the Zanpakuto's name.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It has not been disclosed in the manga yet and no one knows it except for the writer Tite Kubo.

It probably won't be revealed real soon though... I speculate that first Ichigo will master a new power to fight the Quincy king and then there will be a fight between Kenpachi and the king again.

Comment: well, what do you know, your speculation is right, Ichigo has his new power, two Zangetsu's

Answer (score 10):

As of today's (16-04-2014) manga chapter (chapter 577) we got to know how Zaraki Kenpachi's Zanpakuto looks and what its name is.

The name of his Zanpakuto is Nozarashi. Also, in order to get into Shikai state the keyword seems to be "swallow".

How it looks:

[image]

Comment: MS's translation says 'Drink', though. Anyone know what the original Japanese was?

Comment: @Kenneth I think it is: 野晒

Comment: 【[飲み込め](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/%E9%A3%B2%E3%81%BF%E8%BE%BC%E3%82%80)、野晒し】, "swallow" is the more appropriate translation here.

Comment: is this Kenpachi's Bankai or a true Shikai? i remember when he first fought Ichigo he said his Zanpakuto was always in it's Shikai form (never sealed)

Comment: @Memor-X It's his true shikai. See here for abit more info. http://bleach.wikia.com/wiki/Nozarashi#Zanpakut.C5.8D I could edit abit more info about it in the answer itself but i didn't feel like doing that at first since it answers the question as it currently is. and the topic of it being his "real" shikai or not is i feel like stuff for another question :P